# Jumping character in HTML5 game code

Tags: javascript

To make the player jump, I often see the code snippet below. My question is, what is the purpose of using a timer? I assume it prevents double jumping.
Can anyone explain how this works?

```
   if (jumpButton.isDown && this.body.onFloor() && this.game.time.now > jumpTimer) {}
```

Many thanks

Comment: To prevent intentional or accidental spamming of the jump button is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is used to prevent double jump, or spamming jump. Some games especially first person shooter style try to prevent "bunny hopping" which has a history of being seen as a poor play style.